# Can we share a location from the google maps directly to our flutter app?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

Is there a way in which we can share a particular location from the Google map directly into our flutter app where the user can then use that location to either load on a map or use the location info as per their need in the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android, such communication between apps happens using `intent`. Check out the package `receive_sharing_intent` at https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent, this allows your app to catch multiple different intents sharing text or files.

When implemented, your app should show under the apps to share with from Maps. If it doesn't work for locations (I'm not 100% certain), you can take a look at other pub packages, knowing that `intent` is the keyword you're looking for.